# Como declarar un puntero que contiene direccion de punteros char?

Tags: c, punteros, basic

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]El ejercicio dice que apellido es un arreglo de punteros a char (char*)y cada posicion contiene la dirección de memoria de apellidos.

Cuando declaro los datos recibidos en la función ,debería escribir char*apellidos?(que contendría las direcciones)o *int apellidos? Yo supongo que deberia ser con *char Probablemente es tonta la pregunta, pero no estoy segura si declararlo de esa forma o no.

Me refiero a declaralo asi

> void selectos(int * estaturas,char * apellidos);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El prototipo que propones es el correcto. El tipo de datos que el arreglo almacenará será del tipo `(char *)`. Esto dicho en otras palabras es que cada sección de memoria representada por el índice del arreglo almacenará la dirección a un elemento de tipo `char`.

Asumiendo que el apellido a guardar sea `"Ramirez"`, y la letra `'R'` está almacenada en la dirección `0x0A0A05`, y éste corresponda al primer elemento (0) del arreglo, entonces el arreglo contendrá lo siguiente:

`apellidos[0] == 0x0A0A05`

Comment: Será mas complicado utilizar un puntero a `char` porque los cstrings terminan en cero, es más acosejable un puntero a punteros de char (`char **`) que puede definir así: `{ "mateo", "Juan" }` (Como ejemplo)